# Creating topics in SASL/GSSAPI (Kerberos) based Kafka Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kerberos, sasl, gssapi

We have a SASL/GSSAPI (Kerberos) based authentication scheme in our Kafka cluster. Brokers are configured to authenticate with Zookeeper and each other. We added a principal to the "Super Users" list on all the brokers so that we can create topics using that principal, however, topic creation is failing, seemingly because of lack of privileges:

```
[2019-09-11 02:16:30,905] INFO Starting ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2019-09-11 02:16:30,912] INFO Waiting for keeper state SaslAuthenticated (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,157] INFO Client successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,161] INFO Client will use GSSAPI as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,164] INFO Opening socket connection to server broker101.prod/13.14.15.16:2181. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,177] INFO Socket connection established to broker101.prod/13.14.15.16:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,179] INFO TGT refresh thread started. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,193] INFO TGT valid starting at:        Tue Aug 20 02:16:31 UTC 2019 (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,194] INFO TGT expires:                  Wed Aug 21 02:16:31 UTC 2019 (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,194] INFO TGT refresh sleeping until: Tue Aug 20 21:34:57 UTC 2019 (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,203] INFO Session establishment complete on server broker101.prod/13.14.15.16:2181, sessionid = 0x16c60b863b00035, negotiated timeout = 30000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,204] INFO zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,214] ERROR An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7) - LOOKING_UP_SERVER)]) occurred when evaluating Zookeeper Quorum Member's  received SASL token. Zookeeper Client will go to AUTH_FAILED state. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,214] ERROR SASL authentication with Zookeeper Quorum member failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7) - LOOKING_UP_SERVER)]) occurred when evaluating Zookeeper Quorum Member's  received SASL token. Zookeeper Client will go to AUTH_FAILED state. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,215] INFO zookeeper state changed (AuthFailed) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2019-09-11 02:16:31,215] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkAuthFailedException: Authentication failure
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.waitForKeeperState(ZkClient.java:947)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.waitUntilConnected(ZkClient.java:924)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1231)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:157)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:131)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:103)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:85)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:58)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Is it even possible to create topics with a principal other than principal name used by broker to authentication with zookeeper? if yes, then how?

We can successfully create topics using principal which is used by brokers to authenticate with Zookeeper. We were thinking if Super User can perhaps do anything on the cluster, including creating new topics. Is that perception incorrect?

Comment: Read. Your. Logs. `Server not found in Kerberos database ... Zookeeper Client` >> you don't even reach the ZK service, the Kerberos _client_ refuses to start the connection.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter looking at these lines:
"INFO Session establishment complete on server broker101.prod/13.14.15.16:2181, sessionid = 0x16c60b863b00035, negotiated timeout = 30000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)" and "INFO zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)"

It suggests that ZK client was connected successfully. Problem occurred ahead of this step. Or am I interpreting this incorrectly?

Comment: The log states that the client is technically "connected" to the server, but does the server accept any input...?